# Unexpected Token error using UglifyJS with Preact, Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, babeljs, webpack-2, uglifyjs, preact

I'm building a Chrome extension with Preact/ES6/Webpack. I pack using one of 2 configurations: `debug` uses ESLint, Babel and CSS + JSON loaders, `prod` adds 2 plugins: `UglifyJS` and Zip. Here's the `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackCleanupPlugin = require('webpack-cleanup-plugin');
const ZipPlugin = require('zip-webpack-plugin');
const manifest = require('./src/manifest');

let options = {
    // entry file - starting point for the app
    entry: {
    popup: './src/scripts/popup.js',
    options: './src/scripts/options.js',
    background: './src/scripts/background.js'
  },

    // where to dump the output of a production build
    output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'scripts/[name].js'
  },

    module: {
        rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
        },
        enforce: 'pre'
    },
    {
        test: /\.jsx?/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: [
            ['env', {
              'targets': {
                'chrome': 52
              }
            }]
          ],
            plugins: [
            ['transform-react-jsx'],
            ['module-resolver', {
              'root': ['.'],
              'alias': {
                'react': 'preact-compat',
                'react-dom': 'preact-compat'
              }
            }]
                    ]
                }
            },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader'
      }
        ]
    },

  plugins: [
    new WebpackCleanupPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: './src/_locales', to: '_locales'},
      {from: './src/icons', to: 'icons'},
      {from: './src/manifest.json', flatten: true},
      {from: './src/*.html', flatten: true}
    ])
  ],

    // enable Source Maps
    devtool: 'source-map',
};

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  options.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        drop_console: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    }),
    new ZipPlugin({
      path: '../dist',
      filename: `${manifest.name} ${manifest.version}.zip`
    })
  );
}

console.log(`This is a ${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development'} build with ${options.plugins.length} plugins`);

module.exports = options;
```

But when I run the `prod`, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in scripts/popup.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (getLatestValues) [scripts/popup.js:29428,4]

ERROR in scripts/options.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (getLatestValues) [scripts/options.js:29428,4]

ERROR in scripts/background.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (getLatestValues) [scripts/background.js:28678,4]
```

It's worth mentioning that `getLatestResults` is not the only the only function in my code that has `await` in front of it. Also, it should only appear in `background.js` as the other entry points are not supposed to call it.

Also worth mentioning is that if I just comment the `UglifyJS` code, the resulting zipped extension works well.

What configuration piece am I missing to make these errors go away?

Comment: Looks like the uglify somehow runs before babel. Or it doesn't like babel's output format. What exactly is `async`/`await` compiled to, generators? I guess uglify doesn't know the ES6 `yield` keyword.

Comment: I believe it does get translated to `generators`. However, I have other locations in my code that use `async/await` that are not called out for some reason. (Unless Babel implements different calls in different ways, i.e. class methods vs. regular functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that **currently (5/2017)** the built in `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` does not support ES6. When Babel transpiles `await/async` it turns them into `generator`s, which causes `UglifyJS` to throw an error.

There are several alternatives to `UglifyJS` listed in [this article](https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/minifying/#other-ways-to-minify-javascript), but I'm hoping that the Webpack guys will update the plugin, and I'd be able to leave my code intact.

***TL;DR:*** My code is OK; `UglifyJS` does not support ES6; Will support in the future, or will be replaced by alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced `uglify-js` to `uglify-es` for ES6 compatibility:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es

Works fine for me!